# Strings not being parsed correctly in browser

Tags: javascript

I have created this JavaScript code and tried running in chrome:

```
var string1 = "Hello";
var string2 = "Goodbye";

alert(string1);
alert(string2);

string2 = string1;

alert(string1);
alert(string2);

string1 = "Now for something different";

alert(string1);
alert(string2);
```

as you can see, it's supposed to output 6 alert boxes with different outputs, the problem is I'm only seeing 3 (it ends in the 3rd "Hello" variable).

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it displays 6 alert boxes for me.

Comment: about your question [Wrong Value in prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279936/wrong-value-in-prompt).  
I don't know what exactly do you want, but I hope the following is what you want:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wxsbnv66/)

Answer (score 1):

In the seventh line, correct your `alert(string)` to `alert(string2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string1 = "Hello";
var string2 = "Goodbye";

alert(string1);
alert(string2);

string2 = string1;

alert(string1);
alert(string); // change this line with alert(string2);

string1 = "Now for something different";

alert(string1);
alert(string2);
```